# Is this a correct proof for this relation?

Tags: proof-writing, relations

I feel like I am being too brief and maybe incorrect on my proof by contradiction for transitivity/antisymmetry. So is this proof flawed in any way?

A relation R on the set of positive integers is defined by $x \geq y \rightarrow (x,y) \in R$.

Note that $R \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+$

$R$ is reflexive because $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ if $x = y$ then $(x,y) \in R$,

$\therefore R$ is reflexive.

$R$ is not symmetric, consider $(5,3) \in R$ because $5 \geq 3$, and $(3,5) \notin R$ because $3 \ngeq 5$

$\therefore R$ is not symmetric

$R$ is antisymmetric, because if $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,x) \in R$ then $x = y$. We show this by contradiction, assume $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,x) \in R$ and $x \neq y$. Then $x > y$ and $y > x$. $\implies\impliedby$

So then $x=y$

$\therefore R$ antisymmetric.

EDIT: (Thanks Mohan)

$R$ is also transitive: Assume $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$. Then $x \geq y$ and $y \geq z$. Then $x \geq z$.$\square$

Comment: Tip: Use \times to get $\times$ instead of saying "cross".

Comment: @Jim Thanks, I also cant find a good contradiction symbol.

Comment: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @Jim I was actually just using that, and that is where I found \lightning but alas it did not work.

Comment: @Leonardo $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is more readable than $\mathbb{Z}cross\mathbb{Z}$, but too much symbols is also bad. For example, I would write "therefore" or "contradiction" instead of $\therefore$ or some lightning arrows. Your question and its answers should be available to wider audience, including those who do not use those special symbols, e.g. $\times$ is common, but $\therefore$ is not.

Comment: @dtldarek Thanks for the advice, it seems to be fairly clear now thanks to Stahl's edit.

Comment: @Leonardo Where did you prove R is transitive? if $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$ then $(x,z) \in R$. Did you prove this?

Comment: @Mohan It seemed like my proof for transitivity and antisymmetry was so similar that I stuck them together. Can I separate them and say something like "similarly R is transitive?"

Comment: No, it is better if you write it out separately and give the complete proof. If $x \geq y$ and $ y \geq z$ then $x \geq z$.

Comment: @Mohan Nice, I should add that and then I think it is a complete proof. So the part by contradiction is good enough for anti-symmetry?

Comment: It looks fine. But it also depends how deep you want to go  into the proof using the definition of the $\geq$ relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this question has been dealt with in the comments, so if you're happy with it now, please accept this community wiki answer so that it doesn't stay 'unanswered'.  (Community wiki means nobody gets reputation from it.)